# Probability of k male children

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm having trouble with a practice exercise. The exercise is as follows:

[image]

What I have this far:

$P(X=k)=\sum_{n\ge k}P(X=k | N=n)P(N=n)=\sum_{n\ge k}{n\choose k}(\frac{1}{2})^n\alpha p^n$

This is where I get stuck. How do I turn this summation into an explicit formula?

Comment: Tip: $\sum_{j=0}^\infty r^j \binom {k+j} k = (1-r)^{-1-k}$ when $\lvert r\rvert < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clean notation, let $b_k = P(X=k)$.
$$
b_k = \alpha \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^n
$$

Then a common trick when working with sums over an upper binomial index is to add sequential terms and simplify the sum of two binomial coefficients. Thus
$$
b_{k+1} + b_k = \alpha \binom{k}{k}\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^k
 +\alpha \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \left(\binom{n}{k+1}  + \binom{n}{k} \right) \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^n \\
=\alpha \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^k+\alpha \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \binom{n+1}{k+1}  \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^n 
= \alpha \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^k+\alpha \sum_{m=k+2}^\infty \binom{m}{k+1}  \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^{m-1} \\
=\alpha \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^k+\alpha \sum_{m=k+1}^\infty \binom{m}{k+1}  \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^{m-1} -\alpha\binom{k+1}{k+1}  \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^{k+1-1}\\
=\alpha \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^k-\alpha \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^k+\alpha \sum_{m=k+1}^\infty \binom{m}{k+1}  \left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^{m-1}
=  \frac2p b_{k+1}
$$
So there is a recursion relation
$$
b_{k+1} = \frac{b_k}{\frac{2}{p}-1}=\frac{p}{2-p}b_k
$$
with $$b_1 = \alpha \sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{n}{1} \left( \frac{p}{2}\right)^n
= \frac{2\alpha p}{(p-2)^2}$$
The recursion relation is pretty trivial to solve since the factor relating successive terms, $\frac{p}{2-p}$, is constant. So
$$
b_k = \frac{2\alpha p}{(p-2)^2}\left(\frac{p}{2-p}\right)^{k-1}
$$
This is valid for $k\geq 1$; I leave the $k=0$ case to you.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
\sum_{n\ge k}{n\choose k}(\frac{1}{2})^n\alpha p^n=\frac{\alpha}{k!}\sum_{n\ge k} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\left ( \frac p 2\right)^n
$$
and call $q:=p/2$. Then, observe that
$$
\sum_{n\ge k}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}q^n=q^k\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dq ^k}\sum_{n\ge k}q^n
$$
We can compute the right hand side from the geometric sum:
\begin{align}
q^k\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dq ^k}\sum_{n\ge k}q^n&= q^k \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dq ^k} \left (\frac{q^{k+1}}{1-q} \right ) \\
&=q^k \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dq ^k}  \left (q^{-(k+1)}-q^{-k} \right )^{-1}\\
&=q^k (-1)^k k!\left ((-1)^k \frac{(2k)!}{k!}q^{-(2k+1)}-(-1)^k \frac{(2k-1)!}{k!}q^{-2k}\right )^{-(k+1)}\\
&=\frac{q^{k+2k(k+1)}}{((2k-1)!)^{k+1}} \left (\frac{2k}{q}-1 \right)
\end{align}
The result is different from Mark Fischler's one so I expect an error in my computations which I will solve tomorrow, but I still believe this approach to be effective.